# Is C# compiler open source?

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, compiler-construction

Is C# compiler open source?

Comment: Which C# compiler?

Comment: @Allen probably means: "There are several C# compilers, written by several different parties/organizations/groups/teams/people/companies. Which one are you referring to?"

Comment: As an aside, why would you *want* source for a C# compiler? Or asked a different way - what would you change in a C# compiler if you had the source, and are you *sure* that modifying a compiler is the best solution to whatever problem you are having?

Comment: @JeffH sometimes it can be considering the OP must be into language-level design. I mean may be he wanted to create his own language, or study the existing compiler.

Comment: The new .NET compiler ("Roslyn") is now open source.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

At Build 2014, Microsoft announce that their next generation of compilers codenamed "Roslyn" would be made open source and be available on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

The legacy C# compiler from Microsoft is not open source, although it is freely available through [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/) or the .NET Framework SDK.  However there are freely available, open source, C# compilers out there. Check out [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: http://roslyn.codeplex.com/ announced on twitter: https://twitter.com/ahejlsberg/status/451766229187850241

Comment: @heavyd, your answer is outdated. Please update it. C# is completely open sourced nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

[SSCLI](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ssclimsbuild), otherwise known as Rotor, is a shared source version of the CLI + build tools from Microsoft.  Also [Blue](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/02/06/368192.aspx) (as answered by SnapConfig.com) is also a C# compiler written in C#

Comment: Blue download link is broke :(

Answer (score 3):

Look into the Mono project.

Answer (score 3):

Not in the strictest sense but there are some available

like

http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/02/06/368192.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MiniCompiler.aspx

Or Mono

Comment: Actually, gmcs is open source in the strictest sense.

Comment: I meant that the Microsoft's official C# compiler is not open source 
:)